# How to select Kendo tree view node based on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using Kendo treeview control. In my data some nodes have same parent and child node Ids but there is another property 'Type' in each node which is different for each node. My data has three levels

Take this sample example

```
    <div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 10, Type:1,text: "foo", items: [
      { id: 10, Type:2, text: "bar", items: [
        { id: 13, Type:3, text: "baz" }
      ] }
    ] }
  ]
});

var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");

// expand the path of nodes with ID 10 and Type 2
treeview.expandPath([10]);

</script>
```

I want to select node with Id 10 and Type 2 programatically. My treeview is configured with loadondemand set to true (data is big). All I have is Id and Type values to expand and select that particular node.

When I try treeview datasource get method I am getting first matching item, which is id 10 and Type 1 in the above example.

The "expandPath" method requires Ids from parent to child.

How to solve this issue?

Actual settings are like this

```
var treeDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            data: categoryDataSource,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    children: "Children",
                    hasChildren(node) {
                        return (node.Children && node.Children.length > 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

and treeview with these options

```
template: dropDownTreeViewTemplate,
                    dataSource: treeDataSource,
                    loadOnDemand: true,
                    dataTextField: "Name",
                    dataValueField: "Id",
                    select: function (e) {
                        // some code
                    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this recursive function:

```
let expandNodeRecursive = function expandNodeRecursive(id, type, nodes)
{
    let treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");

    if (!nodes) {
        nodes = treeview.dataSource.data();
    }

    var dataItem;
    for (var i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; i++) {
        dataItem = nodes[i];

        if (dataItem.Type == type && dataItem.id == id) {
            treeview.expandPath([dataItem.id]);
        }
        else if (dataItem.items && dataItem.items.length) {
            expandNodeRecursive(id, type, dataItem.items);
        }
    };
};

// Call it without 'nodes' param
expandNodeRecursive(2, 10);
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ApOqabUK)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. expandPath only expanding first node. It is not expanding second node.

Comment: @PSR you need the whole hierarchy under the selected node to be expanded ?

Comment: Yes. If Type is 3 then we have to expand second node also. Because loadOnDemand is true, I think it is not possible to select node without expanding.